# Hide div code (not the div itself) on bootstrap small screen

Tags: html, css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, grid-system

I'm using angularjs combined with ui bootstrap and ngSticky modules to code a web app.

I don't want ngSticky to work a div on bootstrap's small screen. Is there any way I can make the *sticky offset="65"* of the div code below disappear on small or mobile screens? Thanks so much in advance!

```
<div sticky offset="65">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use bootstrap responsive-utilities:

http://getbootstrap.com/css/#responsive-utilities

Make a couple of divs:

```
<!-- this one is visible on larger devices and up and contains sticky attribute -->
<div sticky offset="65" class="hidden-xs">

<!-- this one is visible on small devices and up with no sticky attribute -->
<div offset="65" class="visible-xs-block">
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! The problem is, I don't want the div to disappear on small devices. I just want it to stop sticking on small screens, which can be done if *sticky offset="65"* didn't exist. Do you have an advice on that?

Comment: I think you can use 2 divs.  1 div that will show on xs devices that does not have the sticky attr.  Other div that will show on larger devices that has the sticky attr.

Comment: You will have to put the same stuff in the divs.  But if you use a directive it might help keep it DRY, to avoid copy pasta.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe @media css rule can help in this situation. The solution would be:

```
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .stickyClass {
    offset:65px !important;
  }
}
```

This means that stickyClass will be applied for screen sizes bigger than 768px. You can see this in action [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/4ZgAFNEKFNyN3YfuWMYP?p=preview)